# Angular 2 alpha 22, How to pass down a value to a component through attributes?

Tags: javascript, angular

I declared a component with a selector 'app'
then I used it like follow:

```
<app title="Awesome Title"></app>
```

in the template I wrote this:

```
The title passed {{ title }}
```

I did add write the Component annotation:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    properties: {title:'title'}  // also tried ['title']
});
```

But nothing shows up, the output is

```
The title passed
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, `properties` don't seem to work on the bootstrapped root app.

Try creating a component called 'title-app' and loading it inside of 'app'.

```
// inner component
@Component({
  selector: 'title-component',
  properties: {title:'title'}
})
@View({ template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>'})
class titleComponent{}

// root app
@Component({ selector: 'app' })
@View({ 
  directives: titleComponent, 
  template: '<title-component [title]="Some Title"></title-component>' 
})
class App{}
```

You might also want to use the latest version of Angular2: currently [alpha-26](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.26/). From alpha-26+, if your property is the same name you can just call it once.

`properties: {'title': 'title'}` => `properties: 'title'`

Comment: In case you need to use the root app (for example, because you're passing the properties from static HTML), you still can. You'll have to use ElementRef, though:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#issuecomment-137696843

Comment: Syntax for properties have changed to ['title:title']

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing the most recent version is alpha.26.
The property definition has changed slightly, so here is the new syntax

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    properties: ['title:title']
});

<div [title]="Some Title"></div>
```

I have started a series of blog articles to demo Angular 2 concepts. Check it out here:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-examples

I have a working example of how to assign properties to components via properties. Check out the tree view example as it uses it heavily.

Answer (score 2):

the correct way to do this is:

```
import {
  ComponentAnnotation as Component,
  ViewAnnotation as View, bootstrap
} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Attribute} from 'angular2/src/core/annotations_impl/di';


@Component({
  selector: 'app'
})
@View({
  template: '{{goofy}} stuff'
})
class App {
  goofy:string;
  constructor(@Attribute('goofy') goofy:string) {
      this.goofy = goofy;
  }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

See the full Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/n2XWez69HNJbixH3tEmR?p=preview

However, this is currently broken and is a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858

Comment: i want to use two attributes with the @Attribute let suppose goofy and toffy in this case. but this is not working for me. is there any solution. i am using angular alpha 42. Attribute is working fine for one attribute.

Comment: Looks like the import is now `import { Attribute } from "angular2/core"`.  I'm using alpha 47.